# Javascript: getting session value even session expired

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, session

I am getting session value using javascript code.

```
function checkSessionState()
{
    var sessionUserName = '@Session["FirstName"]';
    alert("Name:"+sessionUserName);
    if (sessionUserName == undefined || sessionUserName == "") {
        window.location.href = "/StepAccount/LogOffFromJavascript";
    }
}
```

and I have set session timeout as 1 minute in web.config file.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1"></sessionState>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

My Query is I am getting session value even session is expired i.e. after 1 minute idle.

Please let us know for any suggestions.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `'@Session["FirstName"]';` renders **once** the page is created. It does not evaluate every time you call a function.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev: then how can check whether session is expired or not in javascript?